# Python Django End_of_file

Tags: python, django, firebase, range, eof

```
def upload(request):
        if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['myfile'] :
            myfile = request.FILES['myfile']
            fs = FileSystemStorage()
            filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
            length=len(filename)
            # sheet.cell_value(0, 0)
            i=1
            wb = xlrd.open_workbook(filename)
            sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
            for i in range(2):
             db.push(sheet.row_values(i))
            return render(request, 'HafrApp/welcome.html')
        return render(request, 'HafrApp/welcome.html')
```

#This code working for me but if I change the range of loop like range(length) its not working and gives a error.

Comment: It looks rather "odd" to use the length of the `filename` as the range to iterate over...

Comment: What is it giving an error?